# Dynamic schema on 10000-100000 records: SQL or NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, nosql

I'm designing a database application that requires a dynamic schema (i.e. the fields of a table is user-defined). Here are the two plans I'm thinking about.

Plan A. MySQL
Since other parts of the system is built upon MySQL, it's easier to implement a SQL schema similar to:

### TableSchema

id
name

### TableField

id
name
table_id
data_type

### TableRecord

id
table_id

### FieldData

id
table_record_id
text_data
int_data
datetime_data
...

Plan B. NoSQL
Or I can setup another NoSQL database (MongoDB?Redis?) specific for this use. And store table schemas and records as individual documents.

The scale of the data should be somewhere about 10000-100000 records. Which plan do you prefer? And what are the pluses/downs I should have in mind? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple database engines is not a recommended pattern for designing an application.
In your scenario, using MongoDb brings you great performance and ease of use, but if you don't need these features, go for plan A.